# Radcombobox OnItemRequested firing page validation

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have some really weird stuff going on here.

I have the following RadComboBox  and button in the master page:

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPesquisa" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"  ShowToggleImage="false" LoadingMessage="Carregando..." HighlightTemplatedItems="true" OnClientKeyPressing="onKeyPressing" EmptyMessage="Buscar" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" OnItemsRequested="rcbPesquisa_ItemsRequested" AllowCustomText="True" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbPesquisa_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="350">
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExcluir" Text="Excluir" OnClick="btnExcluir_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Excluir" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o registro?');" />
```

In the page, I have this validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cuvExclusaoRelacionamento" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Excluir"  OnServerValidate="cuvExclusaoRelacionamento_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

What happens is: When i click the combobox, and it tries to load it's items, cuvExclusaoRelacionamento validator is  called on the server, and of course things go south.
By the way... __EventTarget on cuvExclusaoRelacionamento_ServerValidate is empty

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, and without seeing the full code I'm only guessing, I believe there is no way of getting around this due to the following settings:

1. `ValidationGroup="Excluir"` The ValidationGroup property assigned to an input control is the Validation Group which should be triggered when the control posts back; The ValidationGroup property of a validator control is the name of the group to which it is assigned; Finally the ValidationGroup property of a submitting control (which could be a button but can also be the input control) is the name of the group of Validators to validate the page against before posting back to the server. I should point out at this timethat it will not post back (server-side event handlers will not be triggered) if the validation fails. Given that the validation group of the control is the same as the validation group of your Custom Validator the validator will be triggered when the control attempts to post back to the server (e.g. when being clicked), if this validation fails it will not post back.
2. `AutoPostBack="true"` When you set the control to auto post back it will post back to the server when updated. Given you have an OnClick event I'm guessing you need to perform some server side action when the state of the control is changed.
3. `CausesValidation="true"` When set to true all validators assigned to the same "Validation Group" as the submitting control will be triggered when the control attempts to post back to the server. As I've said above, this will prevent post back (meaning the server-side Event Handlers will not be triggered) if the validation fails.

Given the information provided, I'm guessing that the best action you could take is to set `CausesValidation="false"` for the control. The validation can still be performed so long as you have a submit button (or other control which triggers a post back) elsewhere which is assigned to the "Excluir" Validation Group.

Comment: But my combobox has CausesValidation="false". And when i click it in order to load it's items, it CAUSES the validation, in a validation group that's not even related to the combobox. It's REALLY weird.

What I did find is that the __EventTarget comes empty. So it's like some magic happens and screws up my code

Comment: Is there any javascript that might shed some light on this, i.e. what is the contents of onKeyPressing ? What is the code behind doing? What other event handlers have you got relating to the controls described above, does the page contain ajax? You're right, I'd missed the CausesValidation="false" part before but further information is possibly required to give you more useful help.

Comment: onKeyPressing just checks if Enter was pressed and changes the value of a hidden field. Then on the selectedIndexChanged I check the value of said field to make some things that i don't think are relevant here.

The weird part here is that __EventTarget is empty, like if  no control has sent the postback